# Map not updating with the .putIfAbsent() method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, fluttermap

The items maps don't take any new values after I call the addItem() method.
Here is my provider:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.price,
  });
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};

  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  int get itemCount {
    return items.length;
  }

  void addItem({
    required String productId,
    required double price,
    required String title,
  }) {
    /*check if the items already exist in cart 
    else add the item in cart with quantity one.*/
    if (items.containsKey(productId)) {
      // update the quantity
      items.update(
          productId,
          (existingCartItem) => CartItem(
                id: existingCartItem.id,
                title: existingCartItem.title,
                quantity: existingCartItem.quantity + 1,
                price: existingCartItem.price,
              ));
    } else {
      // add the new item to cart
      items.putIfAbsent(
        productId,
        () => CartItem(
          id: DateTime.now().toString(),
          title: title,
          price: price,
          quantity: 1,
        ),
      );
    }
    // notifying all the listners to update on changes.
    print(items);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here is the Listener:

the badge() is an stateless widget for displaying the shopping cart icon with the number of items in the cart.

This is the badge() (at the top right corner.)[image: Image of the app]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../widgets/products_grid.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';
import '../widgets/badge.dart';

enum FilterOptions {
  favorite,
  all,
}

class ProductOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ProductOverviewScreen> createState() => _ProductOverviewScreenState();
}

class _ProductOverviewScreenState extends State<ProductOverviewScreen> {
  var showFavs = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My Shop'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (selectedValue) => setState(() {
              if (selectedValue == FilterOptions.favorite) {
                showFavs = true;
              } else {
                showFavs = false;
              }
            }),
            itemBuilder: (context) => [
              const PopupMenuItem(
                value: FilterOptions.favorite,
                child: Text("Only Favorites"),
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem(
                value: FilterOptions.all,
                child: Text("Show All"),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          // top shopping card icon button
          Consumer<Cart>(
            builder: ((context, cart, ch) => Badge(
                  value: cart.itemCount.toString(),
                  child: ch as Widget,
                )),
            // taking this out of the builder method as it doesn't need to be re-rendered.
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ProductsGrid(showFavs),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the class where I call the addItem method:
The call is from the icon button at the trailing widget of the gridTile.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);

    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            ProductsDetailScreen.routeName,
            arguments: product.id,
          );
        },
        child: GridTile(
          footer: GridTileBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
            leading: Consumer<Product>(
              builder: (context, value, _) => IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  product.toggleFavorite();
                },
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              product.title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                cart.addItem(
                    productId: product.id,
                    price: product.price,
                    title: product.title);
              },
            ),
          ),
          child: Image.network(
            product.imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the main.dart file (in case needed) I am using multiprovider:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shop/providers/cart.dart';
import 'package:shop/screens/product_detail_screen.dart';

import './providers/products.dart';
import './screens/product_overview_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => Products(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => Cart(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'My Shop',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
          colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(secondary: Colors.deepOrange),
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
        ),
        home: ProductOverviewScreen(),
        routes: {
          ProductsDetailScreen.routeName: (context) =>
              const ProductsDetailScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried clicking the shopping cart icon button. This is the debugger console:

```
Restarted application in 413ms.
2 I/flutter ( 5850): {}
```

2 because I clicked the shopping cart button twice. The 2 would increment by one as I click the shopping cart button. But items are not being added to the items map. The number on the shopping cart icon on the screen remains zero.

I expect to see the number in the shopping cart number update as the products get in the items map.

Comment: The `Cart.items` getter returns a *new* `Map` whenever it is accessed.  Adding items to that `Map` therefore will not affect `_items` and therefore will not affect future accesses to the `Cart.items` getter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was updating the cart.items map rather than cart._items, where I was actually storing the cart items. I got it working as expected.